# Unwanted shutdown when reading a file in C

Tags: c, fopen, esp32, fatfs

I'm using an ESP32 connected to an external memory flash where I mounted a FATFS partition.
I don't understand what could happen if I turn off the ESP32 (and the flash) after a `fopen()` instruction. The main purpose is to avoid any corruption of the file being read or written.
In particular I use a `rb+` argument for the `fopen()` when I read the file, and a `wb` when I write on it.

In which case I can obtain errors on the opened file, if something such as an unwanted switch off of the system happens?

Comment: Check the values returned by the file handling functions. `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` all tell you what happened.

Comment: @WeatherVane you mean that if they all give a correct value then the file is still valid, correct?

Comment: After writing to a file, you can read the file back and compare with the original to check if it is correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane hence I think you are saying that there isn't a standard behavior, it must be experimented.

Comment: You asked what you can do to verify that the file is correct, when all the file functions have returned the correct values. The way to do that is to read the file, but (in general) there is no guarantee that the file is correct even then, and isn't sitting in a cache. Of course you must experiment: that is what testing is all about. Interrupt the process and see if the software behaves correctly. What we seek is a level of confidence. There are never 100% guarantees, ever. For example there might be a glitch that makes your checking software report 'true' when it is 'false', or vice-versa.

Comment: I noticed that turning off the system during a read operation (in particular after the `fread()` but before the `fclose()`) I didn't noticed problems in the values returned by `fopen()`, `fclose()` and `fread()`.

Comment: If you turned it off after `fread()` was successful why was there a problem? Was the data incorrect?

Comment: Data seems to be not corrupted after this kind of operation. In the case of `fwrite()` operation the problem shouldn't exist in my case because I check the size of the file and, if it doesn't coincides with a pre-determined one, the file is deleted. However I'm not 100% peaceful with this topic, if I'll have an opportunity, I'll dig more in depth!